# L’expression « avoir beau », est-elle synonyme complète de « mais »?

Tags: synonymes

Le mot « mais » exprime, en général, une opposition tout comme l’expression « avoir beau », mais son usage me paraît bizarre dans certaines tournures. Alors, dirait-on par exemple :

> Il a beau être stupide, il n’est pas con (Il est stupide, mais pas con)

?

Y a-t-il un décalage de signification entre les deux ?

Comment: Le mot « con » (vulgaire) est un synonyme de « stupide » : http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/con/fr-fr/. On se demande alors ce que cette phrase signifie ; il vaudrait mieux choisir un terme qui dénote une vrai opposition (gâteux,  gaga, arriéré, …).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, on peut parfaitement utiliser *avoir beau* dans ce cas, si ce n'est que *stupide* et *con* sont trop synonymes pour qu'on comprenne le sens attendu.

On pourrait écrire :

> Il a beau être républicain, il n'est pas trumpiste.

ce qui équivaut bien à :

> Il est républicain mais pas trumpiste.

Pour ce qui est de la partie « synonyme complet », pas tout à fait, *avoir beau* ajoute une emphase sur le premier terme.